# Usage of も in そんなこともないけど

Tags: particles, particle-も

Context: a guy has invited his girlfriend over to study, and the girlfriend finds a dirty magazine. The following exchange takes place:

> 男 : 香奈さん? 今日はテスト勉強しにいらしたのでしょう？
> 女 : 何が勉強だし! どうせ千秋はこういうことばかり考えてたんでしょ！
> 男 : そんなこと**も**ないけど…

Why did he say も here instead of saying そんなことないけど or something similar? I can't quite figure out in what sense the particle is being used. It doesn't seem to me a case of it being used in the sense of "even," or trying to show how big of a thing something is. It also doesn't immediately make sense to me for it to be in the sense of "also"; in that case it would mean "that's not the case" (in addition to other things not being the case), but the only way I can make that make sense is if I assume what he means is "I didn't invite you over for that, but I may not have invited you over to study either."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The も is used in the sense of...

> も 〘副助〙*　
>   ⓬ さりげなく取り立てて、文意をやわらげる。...
>   ㋐《多く、文末表現に使って》一歩引く気持ちで、その判断をやわらげる。...
>   「その件なら知らなく**も**ない」「そんな感じがしないで**も**ない」
>   (from 明鏡国語辞典)

The も softens the statement. 「そんなこと**も**ない」 sounds softer and less decisive/assertive than 「そんなこと**は**ない」.

<sub>* 明鏡国語辞典 categorizes 係助詞(binding particles) as 副助詞(adverbial particles).</sub>

Comment: なので・・・千秋くんは、多少「こういうこと」を考えたんでしょうね・・

Answer (score 7):

I will logically strenghen ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ's answer.

- Ａだ。 *It is 100% A.*
- Ａもだ。Ｂもだ。 *It is 50% A.*
- Ａもだ。Ｂもだ。Ｃもだ。 *It is 33% A.*
- Ａもだ。 *It is less than 100% A.*

So, the も softens the statement. "Ａもだ" sounds softer and less decisive/assertive than "Ａだ".