# 言われてみればそうだった気もしてきたな

Tags: meaning, syntax, sentence

I think this sentence means:

> "Now that you mention it, I am feeling good."

Is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 言われてみればそうだった気もしてきたな。

To break it down...

言われてみれば -- now that you mention it
そうだった -- it was so ; that's right ; you're right
気もし～ ← 気がする+も -- I feel~, I think~, I feel like, I have a feeling that~
も -- (particle to make the statement sound softer/milder/reserved.*)
～てきた -- have started to~ ; I'm beginning to~
な -- (sentence ending particle)

Put together:

> "Now that you mention it, I'm beginning to feel like it was so."

<sub>* For more on this usage of も, see: [What is the difference between 「とは限らない」and 「とも限らない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55266/9831) / [Usage of も in a Specific Context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51841/9831) / [も in 「Vのもアレなんだけど」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55970/9831)</sub>

Comment: ～てきた -- have started to~ ; I'm beginning to~ => could you elaborate more? where does this ~tekita come from? Isn't ~始める is the one?

Comment: What I know is ~tekita means to come to, to become which means to became/came to... (~tekuru in the past?) -> source: https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n4-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B-te-kuru/

Comment: ～てくる/～てきた has several meanings and usages. For example... "do something and come back" (eg 買い物に行ってきます。), "gradually change" (eg だんだん色が変わってくる), "start to do" (eg 急にお腹が痛くなってきた。(≂痛み出した・痛み始めた), 雨が降ってきました。), "have been doing" (eg ずっとここで暮らしてきた。), "(some action is done) toward me" (eg 知らない人が話しかけてきた。) etc..

Comment: あっ、なるほど。ありがとうございます、ショコラ先生。

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you might think that, but that would be 気持ちいいな。or something similar.

Your understanding of the meaning of 言われてみれば is good. "Now that you mention it"
BUT,
そうだった is "that was so" or "that's the way it was"
気もしてきた is basically "I have come/begun/started to feel the same way, too"

So now you ought to be able to put the pieces together and re-translate it on your own, I think. ;)

Comment: I really don’t mean to be rude, but don’t you think you should answer a little less? Your answers tend to be incorrect in multiple different ways almost every time... not that there’s any rule against it, but... 

Comment: hmm.  I've got a problem now, because in my original unedited answer, I said that 気もしてきた = "I feel the same way, too". Which I felt was correct, but which received a downvote, causing me to re-evaluate.  

@Darius Jahandarie , I invested time and emotion into this community, and would like to help. I live in Japan and speak Japanese every day, so I do have some value as a source of information. But even wrong answers lead to something being learned, and I don't answer questions that already have an answer I agree with. So I don't feel too bad about trying to help, even if I fail.

Comment: hmm. I see it now.