# Meaning of も in そんなの珍しくもない

Tags: meaning

This sentence is from Doraemon:

> そんなのめずらし**くも**ないよ.

I think it means "It is not that rare/uncommon".
But I don't understand the use of く も here. Should it be interpreted as めずらしく + も?

1. Why did they use めずらしく here? I thought i-adjective + く = adverb while it should be noun in this case.
2. Why did they use も instead of は?
   Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> そんなのめずらしく**も**ないよ。
>   Something like that is not *really* rare.

It's めずらしく + **も** + ない. めずらしく is the ku-form (continuative-form) of めずらしい.

This も is like "well", "(not) quite", or "(not) really". This type of も appears in many sentences, and it essentially makes the sentence sound milder and more reserved. For example, そうではない ("That's not correct") can sound harsh, but そうでもない ("That's not *quite* correct") sounds milder.

Related:

- [Usage of も in a Specific Context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51841/5010)
- [も in 「Vのもアレなんだけど」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55970/5010)
- [What is the difference between 「とは限らない」and 「とも限らない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55266/5010)

Comment: I'm afraid that 'quite' doesn't **quite** work in the OPs example sentence. 'really' or 'particularly' would be better. :-)

Comment: @user3856370 Thank you, edited.

Comment: This still leaves the grammatical question of why it uses a continuative form instead of a noun (or other nominalizer), like めずらしいのもない. Looking at simpler examples, it's easy to internalize a rule that particles are preceded by nouns, or at least nominals, and that doesn't seem to hold up. (Especially if one has been taught to analyze でも as a single particle.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Since 珍しくはない is correct, so is 珍しくもない (both も and は are categorized as 副助詞, which can replace が and を).

Comment: Ah, I suppose it relates to the existence of things like には, then. - Wait, I think I already knew this... ?