# く form of たい form of a verb

Tags: grammar, sentence

I am listening to a song and I came across the sentence,

> 分かり**たく**もないのさ.

What does the く-form of the たい form of a verb turn into? In other words, what is 分かりたく? Is it a noun? Or does it stay a verb? And what is the purpose of turning it into the く form?

And for those interested, the song is pretender by official dism.

Comment: Hint: what do you get if you remove も?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A verb modified with たい behaves just like an i-adjective. So 分かりたくない is just the standard negation: "I don't want to understand".

To understand what difference adding も makes, see [this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65646/meaning-of-%E3%81%8F-%E3%82%82-in-this-sentence).