# Understanding 足はこの程度なら医者に行くほどのこともない。

Tags: translation

The sentence

> 足はこの程度なら医者に行くほどのこと**も**ない。

translates to

> If your foot is only **this bad**, there's no need to go to the doctor.

**Questions:**

1. Where does the notion of "this bad" come from?　Purely from sentence context? Or does the word "程度" imply "degree [of badness]"?
2. What nuance is the "も" adding to the sentence? Is it something like: "...you don't need to *also* go to the doctor"?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Where does the notion of "this bad" come from?

It's from この程度, which literally is "this much", "this degree" or "this extent". More verbosely, this could have been この程度の悪さ ("this degree of badness").

> 2. What nuance is the "も" adding to the sentence?

This is も used to make the sentence sound reserved. See this question: [Meaning of く も in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65646/5010)