# What is the difference between 気がしないでもない and 気がしないのではない

Tags: grammar

> 彼の論文は、構成にはまだ少し問題点がある気が（　　）、内容自体はだいぶ良くなったと思う 
> a) しないのではないが
> b) しないでもないが

I think both are acceptable, in my understanding, they mean the same thing, but the answer says b) is the correct one. So what's wrong with a)?

Answer (score 2):

The explanatory-の is simply unnecessary because 問題がある気がしない serves as the explanation/reason for nothing.

しないではない or しないでもない is a common set expression you can use for double negation. The difference between は and も is not important here. You can use both here, but for the subtle difference, see: [Meaning of く も in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65646/5010)).

a) しない**の**で**は**ないが ❌
b) しないで**も**ないが ✅
c) しない**の**でもないが ❌
d) しないで**は**ないが ✅