# なぜ + ないこともなかった, what is this double negative?

Tags: negation

> でも正直なぜ裕子さんだけと思わないこともなかった

I am very confused about this use of ないこともなかった.

What exactly is it trying to say?

I don't understand the double negative. "I also never happened that I didn't think"?

Answer (score 2):

思わないこともなかった is roughly the same as 思わないことはなかった. It is a double negative expression, "it's not that I did not think" or "admittedly I thought". For this も, see: [Meaning of も in そんなの珍しくもない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65646/5010)

> でも正直「なぜ裕子さんだけ」と思わないこともなかった
>
> However, to be honest, it's not that I didn't think "Why just Yuko?".