# What does のもなぁ　mean?

Tags: particle-の, particle-も

[image]

What does

してもらうのもなぁ　means?

It seems he's saying he won't ask him to do it 5 times in a row?

Answer (score 3):

- **5回連続でしてもらう**: "to get them to do (it) 5 times in a row"
- **の**: nominalizer
- **も**: a special *topic* marker used in place of は to add a "reserved" nuance. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65647/5010).
- **なぁ**: an interjectory particle which is similar to ねぇ but sounds more masculine ("you know", "hmm", "well", etc.)

The corresponding predicate is omitted, but it's mentioned outside the balloon (お互い大変).

> でも流石に5回連続でしてもらうのもなぁ
>
> ≈ でも流石に5回連続でしてもらうのは…。
>
> Still, getting them to do it 5 times in a row is a bit...