# Meaning of そうでもない

Tags: grammar, meaning, reading-comprehension

In this sentence:

> 神野{じんの}菜生子{なおこ}さして意外そうでもなくうなずいた

I'm having some issue in understanding `そうでもない`, and according to how I read it it reverse the meaning of the sentence: as far as I understand, `そうでもない` means "not really", so the sentence would mean something like "Not very/really unexpectedly, Jinno Naoko nodded", but I'm not sure about `そうでもない` and I can't find it on my grammars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation seems okay. To break it down:

- 意外だ: "is unexpected"
- 意外そうだ: "looks unexpected"
- 意外そうではない: "does not look unexpected"
- 意外そうではなく: (ku-form of 意外そうではない) "not looking unexpected"
- 意外そうで**も**なく: "not (quite) looking unexpected"
- さして意外そうでもなく: "not really looking unexpected"

For the last も, see:

- [も in 「Vのもアレなんだけど」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55970/5010)
- [What is the difference between 「とは限らない」and 「とも限らない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55266/5010)
- [Usage of も in a Specific Context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51841/5010)

さして "(not) very/really" is an adverb used with a negative expression (i.e., [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010)).