# かわりもしますよ what is the meaning of this も?

Tags: grammar, particle-も

I usually do not ask a question here unless after trying multiple times I am still stumped and admit defeat.

I understand that かわりもしない would mean "has not changed even a single bit" putting emphasize on the verb as part of the negative, but I do not know the meaning of this も in a positive.

For now I tentatively understand かわりもします here to mean either "he has definitely changed" (ie, emphasis) or "he has changed, among other things" (meaning of 'also' implying other things in addition) but I don't know which or if it's something else altogether.

[image: 市川：…かわったわね、アキラくん… 広瀬：そりゃあかわりもしますよ。今までライバルらしいライバルなんかいなかったんだもの]

Comment: Thanks for adding the image. Very helpful to see the context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This type of も does not mean "also". In this case, it adds the nuance of "of course", "it's only natural" or "it's no wonder". It is used with something that describes a reason or a cause.

- 昨日から何も食べてないの？　そりゃ、お腹**も**空くよ。
- 昨日から何も食べてないの？　そりゃ、お腹が空き**も**するよ。
- 全く連絡がないんだから、心配**も**しますよ。
- たった1000円なら、流石に買え**も**しますよ。(=買えますよ)
- そんなに悪く言われたんじゃ、彼**も**怒るわけだよ／彼が怒り**も**するわけだよ。

In this manga, the reason part is added after the result part.

I could not pinpoint the specific definition in monolingual dictionaries, but basically this should be related to "exclamatory-も" or "も to make the sentence sound reserved". This も is used to vaguely describe "how things turn out naturally".

- [Odd use of も has me stumped](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/5010)
- [Usage of も in a Specific Context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51841/5010)

You can find the same も in the [のももっともだ](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%A0-no-mo-motto-mo-da-meaning/) construction, too.

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to find this meaning of も out on my own.

Comment: Even in English we use "too" (in sort of the "also" sense) to add emphasis. I think "I do too!" (I had to be sure it was "too" and not "to") is an example -- this is, to my ears, a kind of old-fashioned (maybe 1940s American) usage that barely ever comes up anymore and might not even be understood by younger speakers.