# Using も alone to mean 当然 / “naturally”

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-も, resources

I’ve found a usage of も that doesn’t seem to be in any dictionaries, but I’m convinced exists. The structure is:

「〜だから or 〜ば、〜もする」

And the meaning should be:

「〜だから or 〜ば、〜するのも当然のことだ」
“Because ... or If ..., naturally [subject] would ...”

Some examples from the net. Note they all have さ at the end because I found that to be the easiest way to find these examples.

> 1)「好きな男のためなら狡く**も**なるさ」
>
> 2)「何年も風俗で働けば10人や20人位の男と親しく**も**なるさ」
>
> 3)「それぞれ一人分のシーンが終わらな過ぎました。戦闘は長引くし、唐突にドラマシーンは入るし。雑く**も**なるさ。」
>
> 4)「父『おぉ勇者よ、だいぶ大きくなったな！いいぞいいぞー！』 俺はもうじき2歳になる。そりゃ多少はデカく**も**なるさ。」
>
> 5)「一度傷ついたら、臆病に**も**なるさ。」
>
> 6)「けんか**も**するさ。夫婦だもん。」
>
> 7)「そりゃあ泣き**も**するさ！」
>
> 8)「人間なので失敗**も**するさ」

This も also seems to interject set expressions. Example:

> 9)「おいおい私(=女の子)は別に根っからの女好きってわけじゃないんだぞ。ただ周囲の男が魅力なくちゃな。女の子にちょっかい**も**出すさ」

Here, the set expression ちょっかいを出す seems to have been made into ちょっかいも出す to fit this expression (perhaps to avoid the awkward ちょっかいを出しもする). The meaning should be 女の子にちょっかいを出すのも当然のことさ.

Another example from the net:

> 10)「男の子なんだから意地**も**張るさ。ほっといてくれ。」

The meaning should be 男の子なんだから意地を張るのも当然のことさ.

One more:

> 11)「稼げれば平気で嘘**も**つくんだぜ」

Now, I’m not sure if this is a new way of expression or not, but I can’t find any definitions in dictionaries or 日本語文法ハンドブック that suggest that も has this 当然 usage. There’s the 婉曲 usage, but I believe that to be different.

Another good source for the も particle is this paper. But again, it doesn’t seem to document this usage.

https://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/repo/ouka/all/56474/mrj_027_051A.pdf

Does anyone have any leads on or an official source that documents this usage of も?

Comment: How is 雑く supposed to be read?

Comment: @Leebo There is an i-adjective [雑い（ざつい）](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%9B%91%E3%81%84), a highly slangy variant of 雑な.

Comment: Related: [かわりもしますよ what is the meaning of this も?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82516/5010) This usage definitely exists but I have already failed to find this usage in several monolingual dictionaries... BTW, も in Sentence 11 probably just means "even" or "also".

Comment: @naruto Yeah, I agree, 11 might be different, but I feel it can be taken both ways. I don’t think 嘘 is a 最大限の例 of any kind, considering there are much worse things you could do for money, and lying is probably the safest while still immoral thing you could do. You could maybe argue otherwise. Since there’s 10 other examples it’s probably not worthy of a huge debate.

Comment: @naruto Great link, by the way! I see you have other examples of this that’ve come up here and there.

Comment: There is a brief description of this usage on pp. 26-27, 140-141 of [this dissertation](http://hdl.handle.net/11094/72214), which cites 定延利之 (1995)「心的プロセスからみた取り立て詞モ・デモ」益岡隆志・野田尚史・沼田善子 (編)『日本語の主題と取り立て』227-260. くろしお出版.

Comment: @morhetb This is an amazing dissertation! Thanks for sharing it.